# How should I include "outside" content mentioning/related to my site?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content

I have a web shop and I'm thinking about doing a "In the media" page where I would link to other sites/blogs that mention my shop/products and now I'm unsure if I should include a link as a short blog post, e.g.

The site owner is exicted about our stencils, specially about This Product and that Product.

or ... well, I don't have a better idea how to do it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andrija, backlinking is not only a form of appreciation, but the way the internet works. In terms of SEO, this also good practice, since you are basically duplicating content from another site and search engines may penalize your testimonials page for doing so.

By adding backlinks (or a "source" link) where you took the content from, may even help you in ranking better. Why?

- Target site has relevant information to your page/s
- Target site may even backlink to your product page (just make sure you both are not baclinking to each others same page; So your page A links to external page B, that external page B links to your page C [not back to your page A])
- Gives your testimonials/in the media page authority

I wouldn't worry so much about it. Just make a nice page, backlink to their pages where appropriate and carry on ;)

**TL;DR**
Place backlinks to the source information and you're all good.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response :) So If I understood correctly, a few sentences about the content I'm linking and the link itself is "gold"? :)

Comment: Yes, Google loves that and it's also good user experience. If you are quoting the source information, I'd set a backlink like so: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit ..." Source: <link>example.com</link>. If you are writing your own summary about it (and hence it isn't duplicate content) I'd just set a link where appropriate within the context of your summary like so: "Blogger X gave our <link>product</link> a 9 out of 10 stars."